# rxjs repeat api call based on duration specified in response

Tags: javascript, rxjs

#### Context

I need to get data from the server that has a variable expiration (specified in the response). Once it expires I need to get it again. So I would like to create a stream that makes an asynchronous request and repeats that request after a time that is specified in the response of that request.

#### What I tried

Here is my first attempt but the `repeatWhen` doesn't have access to the last response. Instead of doing the repeat every 1000ms I would like to do it based on the expiration property on the response.

```js
const { Observable, defer, of } = rxjs;
const { repeatWhen, delay, map, take } = rxjs.operators;

let count = 0;
function api() {
  return of({ data: count++, expiration: Math.random() * 1000 });
}

defer(() => api()).pipe(
  repeatWhen((notification) => notification.pipe(delay(1000))),
  map((response) => response.data),
  take(5)
).subscribe((x) => { console.log(x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@rc/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

#### Question

Using rxjs, how can I make an api call and repeat it on a delay based on its last response?

#### UPDATE

This technically does what I want but it is a bit hacky... so I would like a better solution.

```js
const { Observable, defer, of, BehaviorSubject, timer } = rxjs;
const { repeatWhen, delay, map, take, tap, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

let count = 0;
function api() {
  return of({ data: count++, expiration: Math.random() * 1000 });
}

const trigger = new BehaviorSubject(0);
trigger.pipe(
  switchMap((expiration) => timer(expiration)),
  switchMap(() => api().pipe(
    tap((response) => { trigger.next(response.expiration); })
  )),
  take(5)
).subscribe((x) => { console.log(x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@rc/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Downvote care to comment?

Comment: why not use web sockets? wouldn't that be nice and efficient.

Comment: @MohhamadHasham That would really just be moving the problem down the stack a level. I have to have a timer somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using the `.expand()` operator, which is meant for recursive purposes. The exact solution is only a few lines:

```
api()
    .expand(({expiration}) => api().delay(expiration))
    .take(5)
    .subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

Here is the [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vaseqolano/edit?js,console).

Comment: Wow, thanks! I have honestly never run across that operator. I ended up using a timer in front of the api though so that it would call the api after the expiration rather than before it. `expand(({expiration}) => timer(expiration).pipe(switchMap(() => api())))`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood completely your question, but what about something like this

```
function api() {
  return of(Math.random() * 10000);
}

defer(() => api()).pipe(
    tap(delay => console.log('delay', delay)),
    switchMap(data => interval(data)),
    take(5)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

**UPDATED ANSWER AFTER COMMENT**

You are already doing the repetition based on what the api is returning to you, and not every 1000 ms. If you run this code it should be clear

```
let count = 0;
const expiration = Math.random() * 1000;

function api() {
    return of({ count, expiration});
}

defer(() => api()).pipe(
    tap(delay => console.log('delay', delay.expiration)),
    switchMap(data => interval(data.expiration).pipe(map(() => data))),
    map(data => ({expiration: data.expiration, count: count++})),
    take(5)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

**SECOND UPDATE AFTER SECOND COMMENT**

If I understand now what you want to achieve, this should help you

```
defer(() => api()).pipe(
    tap(data => console.log('I do something with this data', data)),
    switchMap(data => interval(data.expiration)),
    switchMap(() => api()),
    take(5)
).subscribe(data => console.log('I do something with this data', data));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll modify it to clarify some. I still need the data returned from the api to flow through the stream. I just need to get new data based on one of the properties on the data.

Comment: It looks like it would only hit the api once and then repeat the single response on an interval. What I am looking for is invoking the api on a timeout after its response and then continuing to do that recursively.

Comment: Thanks for another update but the idea was to have each request interval to be based off of the last request rather than all of them based off of the first. I really appreciate all of your effort but I think that the `expand` operator that CozyAzure mentioned does what I want.