# Recursive call with Rx

Tags: rxjs, project-reactor

I'm trying to create a stream that produces the value with delay.

Iterative approach (pseudocode):

```
function f() {
  getCurrentTime()
  wait(TIME)
  httpCall(currentTime, now())

  f();
}
```

Reactive approach:

```
Observable.of(0)
.repeat()
.scan(DEFAULT_TIME, (prevTime, i) -> getNowTime())
.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
.flatMap(fromTime -> httpCall(fromTime, getNowTime()))
```

But my `fromTime` variable does not change.

How to fix reactive code to map it to iterative counterpart ?

Comment: it does not work well. This code produces Flux.just(0)
.scan(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, (prevTime, i) -> LocalTime.now())
.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
.map(fromTime -> fromTime + " " + LocalTime.now())
.repeat() this output 00:00:00      18:01:10
18:01:08      18:01:12
00:00:00      18:01:14
18:01:12      18:01:16
00:00:00      18:01:18
18:01:16      18:01:20

Comment: Try `Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).flatMap(...)`

Comment: That works but I need a constant delay between function executions. That approach can execute function immediately if function compution takes longer that 5 seconds.

Comment: See [this blog post](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2017/09/fixed-rate-vs-fixed-delay-rxjava-faq.html)

Comment: Helpful article. Thanks.

Comment: Consider using `expand` as suggested in this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886776/rxjs-repeat-api-call-based-on-duration-specified-in-response

Comment: Useful operator. Didn't know about it. Thanks.